# Google App Script SQL query returns bool 'True' instead of Int value but query works outside App Script?

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, jdbc

I have a mySQL database which I've connected to through google sheets using JDBC.
In my spreadsheet, I have a list of hashtags and number of times which that hashtag was mentioned that day. Each one of these hashtags is already stored in a table in the databse.

When I try to query the Integar value for a specific hashtags ID number - the value returns as 'true' instead of returning as a number.

If I run the same query outside of app script - it returns the number? I don't understand why. I've tried messing around with the syntax but nothing helps.

.

The spreadsheet is layed out:

Col A: Hashtag

Col B: Number times mentioned

.

The table in the Database is:

Col 1: Hashtag_ID (Int / PK)

Col 2: Hashtag (VarChar)

.

The idea is to track hastag mentions daily.

I'm really stuck with this. It makes no sense.

Thanks in advance.

```
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd); //JDBC connection to DB

var Htag = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue(); //String - Hashtag Text

var HashtagID = conn.createStatement().execute('SELECT id FROM HashtagTable WHERE Hashtag = "'+ Htag + '"');

Logger.log('Hashtag ID Number: ' + HashtagID); //Outputs result of query
```

Comment: It would help if you add comments in your code to indicate what the variables actually output

Comment: Did you understand what Mark said? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69605961/google-app-script-mysql-query-returns-boolean-true-instead-of-integer#comment123032290_69605961 If not, try asking for clarification.

Comment: A little but no not really. I tried executeQuery and got resultset as output. I don't really code so i'm struggling to work out how to use it. I'll be spending a few more hours with doctor google. TheMaster

Comment: Try Read database sample [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc?hl=en#read_from_the_database)

Comment: Got It to work guys
Thanks